# onInstalled opens blank new tab on mobile

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that I'm testing on mobile (Kiwi Browser). The below code snippet works fine on desktop but not on mobile:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
if (details.reason == 'install') {
    let install_window = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    install_window.opener = null;
}});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0"
}
```

What is the difference between desktop and mobile that would make this be the case?

Comment: Use the extensions API like chrome.tabs.create instead of window.open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @wOxxOm in the comments:

> Use the extensions API like chrome.tabs.create instead of window.open